# Project euler question #38 wrong answer? i found an answer that proves better than the one the question provides

Tags: project

Using my program, i arrived at an answer of 9999 which provides a pandigital product of 999919998 and this is the largest possible pandigital number, however this answer is wrong, can someone explain why?
https://projecteuler.net/problem=38 a link to the problem statement

Answer (score 1):

Your number is not [pandigital](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pandigital_number):

> In mathematics, a pandigital number is an integer that in a given base has among its significant digits each digit used in the base at least once.

Your answer is missing the numbers 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 and 7 to be pandigital.

Be aware, that Project Euler calls this the *concatenated product* not the *pandigital product* as stated in your question. I guess this is where the confusion came from.